# How do I validate an attribute of type BigDecimal using Bean Validation annotation?

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf, bean-validation

I'm just wanting to do a simple validation, if the html fields below are sent "null or empty" the user can't persist the data. How can I solve this problem?

below my code

HTML:

```
     <div th:each="msgErrors : ${erros}" class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
<span th:text="${msgErrors}"></span>
     <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
     <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
         </button>
      </div>

        <form th:action="cadastrar" method="post" th:object="${fatura}">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-12">
          <label for="cofins">COFINS:</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" id="cofins" th:field="*{cofins}" placeholder="0,00 %">
                                            </div>
             <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-12">
            <label for="icms">ICMS:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" id="icms" th:field="*{icms}" placeholder="0,00 %">
        </div>
          </div>
         <div class="row mt-4">
       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success mr-3"><i class="far fa-save"></i> SALVAR</button>
                
     </div>
     </form>
```

My Model Class:
@Entity

```
public class Fatura {
     @NumberFormat(pattern = "#,###.##")
    @Column(name = "cofins")
    private BigDecimal cofins;

    @NumberFormat(pattern = "#,###.##")
    @Column(name = "icms")
    private BigDecimal icms;
}
```

My Controller:

```
  public ModelAndView cadastro(@Valid Fatura fatura, BindingResult br){
            
           if(br.hasErrors()){
            ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("cadastro/cadastro");
            mv.addObject("fatura", fatura);
            mv.addObject("listLojas", Lojas.values());
    
            List<String> msg = new ArrayList<String>();
            for(ObjectError objError : br.getAllErrors()){
                msg.add(objError.getDefaultMessage());
            }
            mv.addObject("erros", msg);
            return mv;
           }
```

I need the user to not be allowed to send the fields without typing anything

Answer (score 0):

There are two methods you can use,

- NotNull bean validation
- Constraint in your database for the fields as not nullable

For more info about bean validation check [this](https://www.baeldung.com/java-bean-validation-not-null-empty-blank).